# NextJS ignores lint rules

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm trying to create my first next project. My first impression about it is that setup is very annoying.

I have the following `eslintrc`:

```
const config = {
  "extends": [
    'eslint:recommended',
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': [
      'error',
      {
        allowSingleExtends: true,
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': [
      'warn',
      {
        ignoreRestArgs: true,
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': [
      'off',
      { properties: 'never', ignoreDestructuring: true },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error'],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'no-console': 'error',
    'no-warning-comments': [
      'error',
      {
        terms: ['todo', 'fixme'],
      },
    ],
    'import/order': ['error', { 'newlines-between': 'always' }],
    'import/newline-after-import': ['error', { count: 1 }],
    'import/named': 'off',
    'react/display-name': 'off',
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

When I run `eslint`, then I get a lot of React must be in scope when using jsx. When I run `next lint`, it just ignores things like using random (not defined) variable names.

How do I make `next lint` follow the rules defined in my rc file?